# DataAdapter.Fill() behavior for row deleted at the data source

Tags: .net, ado.net, datatable, dataadapter, rowstate

I'm using the `DataSet`/`DataTable`/`DataAdapter` architecture to mediate between the database and my model objects, which have their own backing (they aren't backed by a DataRow). I've got a `DataAdapter` with `AcceptChangesDuringFill = False`, `AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = False`, and `FillLoadOption = OverwriteChanges`. Here's my understanding of the `DataAdapter` model under these conditions:

### DataAdapter.Update()

- `DataRowState.Added` will result in the `InsertCommand` firing
- `DataRowState.Modified` will result in the `UpdateCommand` firing
- `DataRowState.Deleted` will result in the `DeleteCommand` firing

### DataAdapter.Fill()

- Any row in the returned result set whose primary key corresponds to an existing row in the `DataTable` will be used to update that row, and that row's state will always become `DataRowState.Modified`, *even if the returned row is identical to the current row*
- Any row in the returned result set whose primary key doesn't correspond to any existing row will be used to create a new row, and that row's state will become `DataRowState.Added`
- Any row in the `DataTable` that doesn't correspond to a row in the returned result set will stay at `DataRowState.Unchanged`

Given that I'm correct with this mental model, suppose I want to use `Fill()` to notice deleted rows in the data source. Also, suppose that the parameters of the `SelectCommand` don't return the entire table. I'm guessing that I have two options:

- Find all the rows that should've been updated by the `Fill()` but are still `DataRowState.Unchanged` (relies on my untested italicized assumption above). These rows have been deleted at the data source.
- Clear all relevant rows from the `DataTable` before the `Fill()`; any row that doesn't show up again has been deleted at the data source. This loses the distinction between `DataRowState.Added` and `DataRowState.Modified` that is preserved with the first method.

So, my questions:

- Is my above model of the `DataAdapter` correct, subject to the property values I noted at the top?
- Which option should I go with to find deleted rows? I'd prefer the first one, but that relies on my assumption that all returned rows will be set to `DataRowState.Modified` even if the row is identical; is that a safe assumption?
- Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: You could do a simple test with a single DataTable to check your assumptions... it shouldn't take more that 10 minutes ;)

Comment: I could and I will, but this is the first counterintuitive part of the DataAdapter documentation that I've found so far, and I thought I'd make sure that I'm approaching this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that my assumption is erroneous—if a row returned by the `SelectCommand` is exactly the same as a row already in the `DataTable`, that row remains marked as `DataRowState.Unchanged`. So the proper procedure is removing rows from the `DataTable` before calling `Fill()`, and determining the fate of a row by comparing the new set of `DataRowState.Added` rows to the former list of rows.

Answer (score 1):

I see a similar problem but I cannot use `.Clear` since the `DataTable` is bound to a user interface list and `.Clear` followed by `.Fill` causes the list to lose the user's current selection. Thus, I implemented a (ugly) workaround which basically consists of

1. changing a field in the DataTable to a value that I know this field will never have
2. running `.Fill`
3. removing all rows containing this value

In other words:

```
    For Each drow As DataRow In dset.Tables(0).Rows
        drow.Item("myField") = -1
    Next

    myDataAdapter.Fill(dset)

    Dim drowsRemove = (From drow In dset.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() _
                       Where drow.Field(Of Integer)("myField") = -1).ToList()
    For Each drow In drowsRemove
        dset.Tables(0).Rows.Remove(drow)
    Next
```

Any suggestions for more elegant solutions are appreciated.