# Identify changed rows on DataAdapter.Fill

Tags: .net, dataadapter

I have an application that is run by multiple users concurrently. A datagridview is bound to a datatable that is periodically refreshed via a DataAdapter.

Is there an easy way to identify which rows of the DataTable are updated during a `DataAdapter.Fill`?

I think I could store a copy of the table before the fill, and then compare it with the updated table after, but I'm not sure if there is a built in / more efficient way to get this done.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094682/dataadapter-fill-behavior-for-row-deleted-at-the-data-source for help

Comment: How'd I miss that one when searching?...